# Playwright UI Mode how to import functions

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, playwright

I want to use [Playwright UI Mode](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-ui-mode) to run a specific test-file and be able to import some lines from a helper file `Login.js`.

- It works as long as i do not import from a local file
- If i try to `import {Login_user_foo} from '../commons/Login';` then ui reports that there are no tests

The purpose of the helper file is to not repeat code lines in different test but reuse them like this `await login_user_foo(page)`

This code works with only 1 import

```js
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
// import {Login_user_foo} from '../commons/Login'; // <-- if uncommented then it fails 

test.use({ storageState: './auth/auth_user_foo_qa.json', locale: 'en-US' });

test('Login', async ({ page }) => {
   ... 
});
test('Open list', async ({ page }) => {
   ... 
});
```

But it fails if a second import is added.

```js
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
// the next line causes playwright test --ui to not find any tests
import {Login_user_foo} from '../commons/Login'; 

test('Login', async ({ page }) => {
    ....
```

This is how the error looks like with `import {Login_user_foo} from '../commons/Login';`

[image: Playwright_UI_mode_no_tests_if_import]

The file `Login.js` that is imported looks like this:

```js
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

async function Login_user_foo(page) {

    await page.goto('<our-qa-stage>');
    await page.getByLabel('Remember me').check();                
    await page.getByLabel('Password').fill('<our-password>');    
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Log In to Sandbox' }).click();   
}

export {Login_user_foo};
```

I start playwright ui mode with this command:

```js
// run a specific testfile in ui mode
npx playwright test --ui tests/my_new_test.spec.js
```

### Questions

- Is this a problem with my code or something that ui mode can not handle?
- What do i need to change to be able to import functions from another file?